# ABAddressBook change default sort ordering

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, abaddressbook

Is it possible to change sort ordering and composite name format in iPhone address book with code? There are methods to get these properties (`ABPersonGetSortOrdering, ABPersonGetCompositeNameFormat`) but I didn't find any for setting them.

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697893/how-to-sort-iphone-contact-book/2697942#2697942

Comment: Not even close to be a duplicate. I want to change global iPhone setting, not get people from address book and sort them...

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 7.0 the addressBook API doesn't provide setters to change the sort ordering or the composite name format.

You can, however, pull names from the addressBook and format them to your preferences before you display them.